# Usage of hyphen

Tags: punctuation, hyphens

Is Hyphen correct in the following sentence? If yes, would you explain a little why? Is the phrase adverbial? Does `So` mean "Too" in here?

> Our humanness must be sustained through social interaction **- and fairly constantly so**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should not be a hyphen (-) but an ***em dash*** (—).

The dash here marks what follows it as what *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* calls a ***supplement***: a remark or expansion which is added to the main clause, not an integral part of it.

In this case *so* plays the role of a ***pro-form***: it may stand for an adjectival, adverbial or verbal entity in the same way that a pronoun stands for a nominal entity.

The specific entity which *so* stands for here is *be sustained through social interaction*.

Consequently, the information which the supplement adds is that our humanness must not merely be sustained through social interaction, it must be  ***fairly constantly*** sustained through social interaction.

Comment: As a footnnote, given that many standard keyboards do not have a dash, sometime two consecutive hyphens are used -- as I just inserted into this sentence. (The two hyphens function as a single dash.)

Comment: "The specific entity *so* stands for here is *be sustained through social interaction.*" - did you intend to prepend that with "What"?

Comment: @Andrew Actually, I thought of it as a noun phrase modified by a relative clause with a null-relativizer ... fixing.

Comment: I found it be understandable with a bit of mental squinting :) Your revision is much more readable.